# Node.js on Heroku: PostgreSQL on prod, SQLite3 on dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js/Rails3 app that I'm hosting on Heroku. The rails portion seamlessly switches between PostgreSQL and SQLite3 when it's run on my local machine or the remote production box.

Locally, the rails framework connects to SQLite3 as defined in `config/databases.yml` and when I push to Heorku, the deploy scripts overwrite this with their production setup.

My node.js scripts don't have a framework that Heroku can hook into and make sure I'm using the right database in my production environment.

How can I make my node.js scripts "Just Work" the way my Rails app moves seamlessly between development and production environments?

Comment: Noted, see comment in Brandon's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku exposes a database URL you can connect to via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. Here's the relevant section from the [Heroku Dev Center docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js#using_a_postgres_database).

> #### Using a Postgres Database
>
> To add a PostgreSQL database to your app, run this command:
>
> ```
> $ heroku addons:add shared-database
> ```
>
> This sets the `DATABASE_URL`
>   environment variable. Add the `postgres` NPM module to your
>   dependencies:
>
> ```
> "dependencies": {
>   ...  
>   "pg": "0.5.4"
> }
> ```
>
> And use the module to connect to `DATABASE_URL` from somewhere in your code:
>
> ```
> var pg = require('pg');
>
> pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
>   var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table');
>
>   query.on('row', function(row) {
>     console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: Which works very well on my production environment, but fails to take into account that I'm using sqlite3 on development. 

In truth, I've actually dropped Node in favor of an all-rails project. So the issue is moot for me. Let's still find an answer, for others' reference, and I promise to accept it if it works. =^]

Comment: As mu is too short pointed out in a comment to the OP, it would probably be easier to just use PostgreSQL in both environments, and then implement this solution.

Comment: Indeed. To address the issue, though, you could define your own environment variable on Heroku (as shown in the docs) and check for that upon startup; if it exists or is set to `PRODUCTION` (or whatever) use the Heroku port; else use some development environment, perhaps defined via config file (very similar to `RAILS_ENV`).